# Javascript/HTML Oninput with div

Tags: javascript, html

I've made `oninput` for `div` with a class. I can't add an ID to the `div`. So here is my script:

```
var objecto = document.getElementsByClassName(" nicEdit-main ")[0];
objecto.oninput = function() {
    alert("Ok!");
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class=" nicEdit-main   " style="width: 499px; margin: 4px; min-height: 149px; overflow: hidden;" contenteditable="true">1123215545<br></div>
```

Why does `oninput` not work for this div?

Comment: Is there any error in your browser console

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r84rtmx5/1/ - make sure you are running the script after the target element is loaded in the dom

Comment: thanx for this lesson. Write into answers. THanxc for help @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should just work fine, make sure your script is executed after the target element is loaded in the dom.

1 way is to use the dom ready/window load event handler

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var objecto = document.getElementsByClassName(" nicEdit-main ")[0];
  objecto.oninput = function() {
    alert("Ok!");
  }
})
```

```html
<div class=" nicEdit-main   " style="width: 499px; margin: 4px; min-height: 149px; overflow: hidden;" contenteditable="true">1123215545
  <br>
</div>
```

---

Another is to place the script after the element like

```html
<div class=" nicEdit-main   " style="width: 499px; margin: 4px; min-height: 149px; overflow: hidden;" contenteditable="true">1123215545
  <br>
</div>
<script>
  var objecto = document.getElementsByClassName(" nicEdit-main ")[0];
  objecto.oninput = function() {
    alert("Ok!");
  }
</script>
```